# Trouble with accessing Object property in vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, object-notation

I am trying to access an Object property in vue component computed property but I am getting an error saying the property is undefined. I have setup a prototype [here](http://test-scores.surge.sh/). When I try to use

```
playerEntry.stats.RecYards["#text"] > "0"
```

Vue complains

> [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: playerentry.stats.RecYards is undefined"

and looking in vue.js devtools under Computed I see **playerReceivingStats:"(error during evaluation)"**
here is the pertinent code:

boxscore.js

```
const boxScoresStats = {
  stats: Vue.component("box-scores", {
    props: ["props_box_score", "props_gameID"],
    data: function() {
      return {
        playerStats: this.props_box_score.data.gameboxscore.awayTeam.awayPlayers
          .playerEntry
      };
    },
    computed: {
      playerPassingStats: function() {
        return this.playerStats.filter(playerEntry => {
          return playerEntry.player.Position === "QB";
        });
      },
      playerReceivingStats: function() {
        return this.playerStats.filter(playerEntry => {
          console.log(playerEntry.stats.RecYards["#text"]);
          return playerEntry.stats.RecYards["#text"] > "0";
        });
      }
    },
```

Template

```
<div v-for="playerStats in playerReceivingStats">
    <tr class="d-flex">
        <td class="col-3 justify-content-center" scope="row">
        {{playerStats.player.FirstName}} {{playerStats.player.LastName}} ({{playerStats.player.Position}})
        </td>
        <td class="col-2 justify-content-center" justify-content="center">
            {{ playerStats.stats.Receptions['#text'] }} </td>
        <td class="col-3 justify-content-center">{{playerStats.stats.RecYards['#text']}}</td>
        <td class="col-2 justify-content-center">{{playerStats.stats.RecTD['#text']}}</td>
        <td class="col-2 justify-content-center">{{playerStats.stats.Targets['#text']}}</td>
    </tr>
</div>
```

I have tried both bracket and dot notation but still no good. I see the values from the console.log printing out ok. But I am at a loss as to why it says undefined when I can see the object property in devtools. Also note if I shorten the eval in computed to **playerEntry.stats.RecYards** I get no error? But I then get incorrect results. Any help much appreciated.

**Updated:**

Here is the computed property that works:

```
 playerReceivingStats: function() {
        return this.offensivePlayers.filter(playerEntry => {
          if (typeof playerEntry.stats.RecYards != "undefined") {
            return playerEntry.stats.RecYards["#text"] > "0";
          }
        });
      }
    }
```

Comment: The `RecYards` property is missing for that player. When I try it it seems to be `Logan Cooke`, id `14702`, `this.playerStats[11]`. The logging you're seeing is for the first few players, which work fine, but it falls over when it gets to that player.

Comment: Try setting `playerStats` as a computed property instead of a data property.

Comment: Regarding the update: It is `playerStats[11]` that is missing the relevant field. The picture shows `playerStats[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add created hook to set the props value to data property

```
data: function() {
      return {
        playerStats: { 
         stats: {
           RecYards: {}
         }
        },
      };
    },
created() {
  this.playerStats = this.props_box_score
                         .data.gameboxscore.awayTeam.awayPlayers.playerEntry;
}
```

Comment: Sorry still getting "playerEntry.stats.RecYards is undefined" with update.

Comment: Can you please try again with the above approach?

Comment: Sorry still  "RecYards undefined"

Comment: `props` are available within the `data` function, you don't need to use `created` to copy them across. There's an example of this within the official documentation, https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#One-Way-Data-Flow

Comment: Yes I see because computed property "playerPassingStats" uses "playerEntry.player.Position" no problem. Any ideas on what is going on here?

Comment: @Alan I believe I have already explained what the problem is in the comment I posted on the question. The data you're trying to use is simply missing from the server response.

Comment: See updated image from devtools. Do I not see "playerEntry.stats.RecYards' in copy. And I can console.log the object property?

Comment: my fault. I didnt look thru all the results. I will have to put an additional test in function check. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your child component has probably loaded before the data has become available in the parent component. Remember, JavaScript is asynchronous, so your component rendering may be happening before the data is even available.

You can use conditional rendering on your component to render the component once the data is available.

```
<my-component v-if="someCondition">
```

You will then need to go through your code, find the point at which that data becomes available, and then set `someCondition = true`, once this flag is flipped, your component will render, and the data it is dependent upon will be available.

Use `v-if` as opposed to `v-show`. If you use `v-show`, your component will eagerly render but just be hidden by CSS. If you use `v-if` your component will lazily render once the condition is true.